# Apply gradient in pie chart - iOS charts library

Tags: ios, swift, charts

I have created a pie chart using Charts library in Swift.

When I am trying to pass CGColor to make the colors of the charts it is not accepting it.

Here is how my current code looks like:

```
let colorLV1 = [color.heatWheelOrange, color.heatWheelOrange, color.heatWheelSkyBlue]
let chartDataSetLV1 = setChartDataset(dataEntries: dataEntriesLV1, colorCode: colorLV1, valueTextColor: UIColor.black, fontFormat: fontMedium)
func setChartDataset(dataEntries : [PieChartDataEntry], colorCode : [UIColor], valueTextColor : UIColor, fontFormat : NSUIFont) -> PieChartDataSet {
    let chartDataSet = PieChartDataSet(values: dataEntries, label: "")
    chartDataSet.colors = colorCode
    chartDataSet.sliceSpace = 1
    chartDataSet.selectionShift = 0
    chartDataSet.valueTextColor = valueTextColor
    chartDataSet.valueFont = fontFormat
    return chartDataSet;
}
```

To display gradient I am changing `colorCode : [UIColor]` to `CGColor`. However it throws an error.

Is there a way I can change the color to gradient in Swift using charts library?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking into the ChameleonFramework if you haven't already https://github.com/viccalexander/Chameleon

I've used it in conjunction with Charts for gradients on bar charts, but I assume it would work in a similar way with pie charts. With ChameleonFramework, my code looks something like this;

```
    let color1 = UIColor(hex: 0x79D3DB)
    let color2 = UIColor(hex: 0x5773D3)

    let gradientColor = UIColor(gradientStyle: UIGradientStyle.topToBottom, withFrame: barChartView.frame, andColors: [color1, color2])

    var gradientColors = Array(repeating: gradientColor, count: 7)

    chartDataSet.colors = gradientColors as! [NSUIColor]
```

That should prevent you having to deal with UIColor > CGColor conversion issues. Hope that helps!

Comment: Works well for a bar chart because the frame is predictable, but no clue how to specify the frame for each individual slice on a pie chart